# Checking the sign of an expression

Tags: equation-solving

In checking the following equation's sign,

```
Assuming[0 < x < 1/2 && 2 x + o <= 1, Sign[(2 x Log[1 - o] + (2 x + o x) Log[1 + o])/(o^2 x)]]
```

I am surprised by the result:

```
Sign[2 x Log[1 - o] + (2 x + o x) Log[1 + o]]/(Sign[o]^2 Sign[x])
```

The reason I am surprised is that, given the stated assumptions, there is no question that the sign of the denominator is positive. This makes me wonder if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: `Assuming`, on its own, does not do anything except temporarily set `$Assumptions`, which is the default value of the `Assumptions` option of some functions. Thus, `Assuming` will effectively set the `Assumptions` option on applicable functions (such as `Simplify`, `Refine`, `Integrate`, etc.) inside of the `Assuming`.

Comment: Note that `Sign[0]` is `0`, thus `Sign[x^2]` is not `1` for any real `x`. Add `o != 0` to the assumptions and use `FullSimplify`.

Comment: Assumptions have no effect unless used with a function that accepts the option `Assumptions`, e.g., `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `Integrate`.